# Error on saving object in AFIncrementalStore. ResponseObject is an NSArray instead if NSDictionary despite valid JSON resposne

Tags: afnetworking, afincrementalstore

All,

I am trying to solve an issue now for the last two days and seem incapable. Apologies in advance if asking for the obvious.

In a very simple data model I try to insert a new object user. (attributes: name, password and id which are respectively a NSString, a NSString and a NSNumber). The new object gets successfully created
in the API and the external MySQL server. However, in the completion block of the HTTPrequest when
(I think) the backing store is populated it tries to create the resource identifier.

This is were the app crashes in this method when it is trying to get allKeys from the representation dictionary:

(NSString *)resourceIdentifierForRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)representation ofEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity fromResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
The JSON response getting back from the server is as follows:

[{"id":20,"name":"john doe","password":"secret"}]

Anyone a clue? Would be very grateful if I could solve the issue this year!!!

Side notes: Matt great job!

Side question: How will AFIS deal with local storage, local changes and synching with the server when a connection is back?

All,

Thanks in advance and enjoy 2013!!!

[Update]

The issue is that I get an NSArray back instead of a NSDictionary. I can simply fix it by changing the code in AFIS savecontext to pass the responseObject[0] however I prefer not to change the AFIS code and I still find it odd that I dont get an NSDictionary back when I have a valid JSON response

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method that AFIS uses to get the resulting object from the json data.

```
- (id)representationOrArrayOfRepresentationsOfEntity:(NSEntityDescription*)entity
                              fromResponseObject:(id)responseObject
```

The response object should be your array with dictionary at index 0.